# Cakephp and opauth login problems

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redirect, oauth

currently i'm trying to implement the opauth plugin for cakephp found [here](http://www.opauth.org) using the facebook strategy at present. I've followed the instructions however when I attempt to login using my facebook account I am redirected to the login page. What I have noticed is that the authentication is occurring and successful using this->Auth->login($user) where $user is an array of the user's stored information, but on redirection, the login function of my UserController is called an I'm returned to the login page. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Turns out its a config setting, I noticed it while staring at his commit comments on github. In the config of the plugin the default option for the callback transport was changed from session (losing the session was my issue) to post. The change can be seen [here](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth/commit/c11fbdf4d27838f9eee154e70f1459581b9c2839). After making that change to the config everything worked.